# Platform dependent SVG splash graphics

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, csproj

In order to deal with Google's [decision to mangle splash screen graphics for Android 12+,](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10604) and still have the splash look acceptable on iOS, I have two logos, chosen depending on platform. The following lines in my csproj file are designed to achieve this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
...
    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen
        Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) != 'android'" 
        Include="Resources\Splash\logo_filled_withtext_whiteondarkb.svg" 
        Color="#4D8F8D"
    />
    <MauiSplashScreen 
        Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'" 
        Include="Resources\Splash\logo_filled_withtext_whiteondarkb_android12.svg"
        Color="#4D8F8D"
    />
...
</ItemGroup>
```

This works, in that the splash graphics are correctly selected for each platform.

However, the VS build process is not so straightforward: only the first `<MauiSplashScreen>` element is translated into a `.png` file. This results in a runtime error when the second `.png` is needed but cannot be found. I have to reverse the order of the elements and build again before I get both versions rendered. (It's fine after this, but the problem recurs whenever the `obj` folder needs to be regenerated.)

Only the first element is displayed in solution explorer, too, but I can live with that.

Is there a better way to handle this conditioning so that resizetizer will create both `.png`s at once?

Comment: You can try to update the app manifest to reference your custom splash screen image. Please check this [Platform-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#platform-specific-configuration).

Comment: Thanks @GuangyuBai-MSFT, what information on that page should I be looking at? It suggests _using_ platform specific config in certain (unspecified) scenarios, but I can't see any info or links on how to actually _do so_. Just to be clear: the app is being deployed correctly, when the images are available, the problem is that the build process is only creating some of the necessary images from the source svg.

Comment: I mean you can change the splash screen path in the Android manifest fille and IOS Info.plist.